# The checkbox check if it is checked does not work

Tags: javascript

I have a problem seeing if the checkbox has been checked.

In particular, I have a table with id, name and country and an additional column with a checkbox. The purpose is to return all the ids of the checkbox that has been selected. But
what I notice is that the if statement doesn't seem to work.

Can you kindly help me?

```js
function GetSelected() {
  var table = document.getElementById(mytable);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  console.log(rowCount)
  for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = table.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    if (chkbox[i].checked) {
      var row = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.parentNode;
      id_art += row.cells[0].innerHTML;
      console.log(id_art);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="my-table" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th style="width:80px">Check</th>
    <th style="width:80px">Id</th>
    <th style="width:120px">Name</th>
    <th style="width:120px">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John Hammond</td>
    <td>United States</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Mudassar Khan</td>
    <td>India</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Suzanne Mathews</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Robert Schidner</td>
    <td>Russia</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Get Id Selected" onclick="GetSelected()" />
```

Comment: `var chkbox = table.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");` why are you looking this up in the loop?

Comment: `var cbs = document.querySelector('#tableId input[type="checkbox"]:checked'); const ids = Array.from(cbs).map(cb => cb.closest('tr').id);`

Comment: @caramba I put the part in html

Comment: @epascarello - should that be `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: whoops.... yeah

Comment: @epascarello it does not work, also with querySelectorAll

Comment: What does `chkbox` yield? What is `checkBoxes`?

Comment: `document.getElementById(mytable)` Where is `mytable` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab all the checked checkboxes and loop over them to get the text in the next td element.

```js
function getSelected() {
  var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('#my-table input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  console.log(cbs.length);
  const ids = Array.from(cbs).map(cb => cb.closest('td').nextElementSibling.textContent);
  console.log(ids);
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="my-table" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th style="width:80px">Check</th>
    <th style="width:80px">Id</th>
    <th style="width:120px">Name</th>
    <th style="width:120px">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John Hammond</td>
    <td>United States</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Mudassar Khan</td>
    <td>India</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Suzanne Mathews</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Robert Schidner</td>
    <td>Russia</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Get Id Selected" onclick="getSelected()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query over the **checked checkbox** elements using `forEach()` or a `for()` loop and then go to the closest `tr` up the dom tree using `closest('tr')` and get the textContent of the child using the key that is set for your `tr` *ID* section => '***2***', since that is the *third* `td` element in your `tr`.

***NOTES:*** In your example you did not define the variable **mytable** you are passing into your function.

Rather than using two parentNodes to get up two level, use [**.closest()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Within the loop, using the keys to get the proper children:

- **Check** `td` section of your table would be `.children[1]`
- **Id** `td` section of your table would be `.children[2]`
- **Name** `td` section of your table would be `.children[3]`

If this is ***not*** what you are looking for let me know and I can update or remove this answer.

```js
function GetSelected() {
  let checks = document.querySelectorAll('#my-table td input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  checks.forEach(cb => console.log(cb.closest('tr').children[2].textContent))
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="my-table" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th style="width:80px">Check</th>
    <th style="width:80px">Id</th>
    <th style="width:120px">Name</th>
    <th style="width:120px">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="1">
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John Hammond</td>
    <td>United States</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Mudassar Khan</td>
    <td>India</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Suzanne Mathews</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Robert Schidner</td>
    <td>Russia</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Get Selected" onclick="GetSelected()" />
```